# Soy's medical efficiency - don't get the meaning of the paragraph as a whole

Tags: meaning

> "Mark Messina's book *The Simple Soybean and Your Health* exudes recognition much less unrestrained in the description of the soy's medical efficiency than its versatility, but the author cautions against soy to be a panacea."

I've translated all the difficult words as: exude (emit/ooze) and panacea (cure all). However I don't catch the meaning of " exudes recognition much less unrestrained in the description of the soy's medical efficiency than its versatility" as a sentence.

I think that the meaning is:

> the author thinks the soy's efficiency is less effective in comparison to its versatility?

By the way, what is a versatility of soy? Does he mean that you can use it for a lot of purposes?  But it's not effective although the variation?

Answer (score 1):

Wow! What a horribly written sentence. I think the writer was straining to sound erudite and ended up sounding semi-literate. Here's what I think he/she is trying to say:

"Mark Messina's book *The Simple Soybean and Your Health* is much more restrained in describing soy's medical efficacy than its versatility, with  the author cautioning against seeing soy as a panacea."

Simple is best!